# Unable to do make clean despite .PHONY

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

I have created a Makefile, to convert markdown to other formats. I have used `.PHONY: clean` but I am still unable to do `make clean`. It searches for `clean.md` file. I know its because of `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` but I need it to convert just one file.

```
SOURCE= $(wildcard *.md)
## Pattern Substitution
HTML=$(SOURCE:.md=.gen.html) 
PDF=$(SOURCE:.md=.gen.pdf) 

## Targets and dependencies
.PHONY: all
all : $(HTML) $(PDF)

html:   clean $(HTML)
pdf:    clean $(PDF)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    - $(RM) -f *.gen.*

.PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS)
$(MAKECMDGOALS): $(MAKECMDGOALS:%=%.html) $(MAKECMDGOALS:%=%.gen.pdf)

%.gen.html : %.md
    $(PANDOC) $(PANDOC_OPTIONS) $(PANDOC_HTML_OPTIONS) -o $@ $<

%.gen.pdf : %.md
    $(PANDOC) $(PANDOC_OPTIONS) $(PANDOC_PDF_OPTIONS) -o $@ $<
```

Please suggest changes.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GOALS := $(filter-out clean, $(MAKECMDGOALS))

.PHONY: $(GOALS)
$(GOALS): $(GOALS:%=%.html) $(GOALS:%=%.gen.pdf)
```

Comment: May I ask you one more question: is (GOALS:%=%.html) same as (GOALS:=.html)

Comment: Also do we have to filter-out  all? If yes is this ok: GOALS := $(filter-out clean, all, $(MAKECMDGOALS))

Comment: Yes, all should be filtered out, too